# Django - getting a syntax error in a class generic view

Tags: python, django, view, syntax

These are my URL's.

```
url(r'^$', views.index.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^([\w-]+)/$', views.board_lv.as_view(), name='board'),
url(r'^comments/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.detail.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

And here is the relevant view:

```
class board_lv(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'boardList.html'
    context_object_name = 'notice_List' 

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.Board = get_object_or_404(Board, name=self.args[0])
        if self.args[0] == 'all':
            return Notice.objects.order_by('-posted_on'))
        else:           
            return Notice.objects.filter(board=self.Board)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(board_lv, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)  
        context['c_board'] = self.Board;
```

The traceback paste can be found here: http://dpaste.com/1355104/

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

EDIT: turns out it was an indentation problem, I need to find something better than gedit i think.

Now my html page doesn't seem to be working, and I can't figure it out:

```
<h1>/b/{{c_board}}</h1>
<ul>
{% for n in notice_List %}
    <li>
    {% if not n.isText %} 
        <h2><a href="{{ n.content }}">{{ n.title }}</a></h2>(/b/{{n.board}})<br>    
    {% else %}
        <h2><a href= "{% url 'detail' n.id %}">{{ n.title }}</a></h2>(/b/{{n.board}})
        <p>{{ n.content|slice:":100" }}</p>     
    {% endif %}
        <a href="{% url 'detail' n.id %}">Comments</a>{{n.thumbs_up}}   
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Everything after the first "/b/" doesn't appear. I think it may be something to do with my context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra parenthesis on this line:

```
return Notice.objects.order_by('-posted_on'))
```

It should be this:

```
return Notice.objects.order_by('-posted_on')
```

Comment: I've come across another issue, it's in the description, could you have a look?

Comment: @user2712322 - I'm sorry, but I don't really know anything concerning django.  I just took a look at your question originally because it said "syntax error" and, usually, those are just misplaced parenthesis or something. :)

Comment: Regarding your edited issue - you have to return the `context` in the `get_context_data`